# Move all files of certain file type using SVN

Tags: svn, command-line

I have a directory full of image files. I want to move all the .jpg files one directory up

```
$svn move *.jpg ../ 
$svn: Client error in parsing arguments
```

As you can see this approach doesn't work.

If this isnt possible how do I move ALL the files up one directory?

SVN version 1.4.4 on OSX 10.5

Comment: it works on svn version 1.6.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need some shell script to do this, e.g.

```
ls *.jpg | while read i; do svn move "$i" ../; done
```

Comment: Or the shorter `for i in *.sql; do svn move $i ../; done` (_Front Against Useless Use Of Pipe_)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from the [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) you can't do this with pure svn. If you want to move/copy all files, then must move/copy the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with 1.5/1.6 client but not with 1.4 never the less you have to quote the parameters to prevent the shell to expand the parameters.